# Linear Regression Idiosyncratic Noise

Tags: regression, normal-distribution, noise

$$
y = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x + \varepsilon, 
$$
where $\varepsilon\sim N(0,\sigma e). $

How do I calculate epsilon in this context? I know and understand all of the other variables however I cannot seem to figure out epsilon.

Comment: So I have 100 values for x (predictor values) and I need to generate 100 values for y (response values) using the above equation. I know both beta values and the standard deviation. How am I supposed to generate those y values if I can't calculate epsilon?

Comment: The question is much clearer with the info in the comment - please edit the information into the question itself.  I think it would be useful to also briefly explain _why_ you need to generate these values

Comment: @Will the error team (epsilon) is normally distributed with the mean of 0 and standard deviation of σe. You generate those error term randomly from the given distribution and add them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, but you can't calculate epsilon. In fact, epsilon stands for the part of the response you can't predict with your linear model. If you want to predict $y$, your prediction will never be perfect, because there is always a part you can't predict.

However, if your model is accurate enough, epsilon will be small. Hopefully, it will be small enough for your predictions to be useful.

Furthermore, since you assume that epsilon is normally distributed - which is a common assumption - you can make statements about the distribution of y, and even give your predictions as confidence intervals.

Answer (score -1):

The ε is the difference between your prediction and the target.

ε = y-(β0+β1x)